# What does the form-inputs HTML class do in simple_form?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Doing a code search for "form-inputs" in the simple_form github repo [indicates](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=form-inputs) it's added as an HTML class in generated templates for ERB, slim, and erb. For example, in the HAML template file `_form.html.haml`:

```
= simple_form_for(@<%= singular_table_name %>) do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
  <%- attributes.each do |attribute| -%>
    = f.<%= attribute.reference? ? :association : :input %> :<%= attribute.name %>
  <%- end -%>

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

However, I can't see the HTML class being used within simple_form or elsewhere (such as Twitter Bootstrap). For example, I can't find any CSS files changing the styling of divs with the form-inputs class.

What is the purpose of the `form-inputs` class?

Comment: Perhaps it's just for the standard-practice convenience of being able to modify it in the future. Otherwise, you'd place a simple `div` there, which is less elegant.

Comment: @WesFoster beginner question: what'd happen if there wasn't any `div` at all?

Comment: Surely the div is just there if you need it, because it is not really hurting anything and makes achieving particular styles much simpler. With it, you can more easily create forms that (loosely) resemble the "static example" modal at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals (I know there is no form, I am referring to the "border" and padding around the body).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was [ostensibly added to "make it easier to integrate with bootstrap"](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/commit/612c0067cf0313cd02c33c4870413a15e96a261a). It replaces a similar wrapper div with a different class. As you've pointed out, this is more relevant for `form-actions` than for `form-inputs`, so the latter is most likely just a convenient way to encapsulate all of the fields in a consistent way.

Comment: The discussion referenced in the linked ticket can provide a little more insight. https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/424